# MONTH IN MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

When executing the code , Datatype mismatch Error is showing .Can tell if i need only Month(either as January,February.. or as **1 ,2,...12**) as a field in MS Access database what should i give as data type.

Thanks for your answer.One more query:

if (rs6("TotalDays")+ tdays) > rs5("Sing") then

Is there any syntax error in this statement..?

tdays holds the number.

Comment: It depends on what tdays holds. I am always a little worried when someone has six recordsets, it seems likely that there is an easier way.

Comment: Is this two questions or one?

Answer (score 1):

`Month()` in access takes a parameter of type `DateTime` and returns the number of the month. To get the month name, you could either do `FormatDate(Month(yourDate), 'mmmm')` or `MontName(yourDate)` (in Access 2000 and later).

See [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/190705-extracting-month-name) for more info.